# _reactNativeFetchBlob2.default.writeFile is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

TypeError: _reactNativeFetchBlob2.default.writeFile is not a function

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';


RNFetchBlob.writeFile(path, data, 'utf8')
                .then((success) => {
                    console.log(success);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing `fs`... `RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile`.